# setTimeout Function is ignored with submit, with button everything is fine

Tags: jquery, html, button, submit, settimeout

Actually my code is following:

```
<form method="post" action="" id="form">
  <input type="submit" value="Anlage Ein" id="power_off" title="Anlage Ein">
</form>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#power_off").click(function() {
    setTimeout("alert('Boom!');", 2000);
  });
});
```

It is not working that the alert will show up. If i replace the submit with an normal button its working. I don't understand why. For me it is very important to use the submit combining with the setTimeout.
The following code is working:

```
<form method="post" action="" id="form">
  <input type="button" value="Anlage Ein" id="power_off" title="Anlage Ein">
</form>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() { 
  $("#power_off").click(function(){
    setTimeout("alert('Boom!');", 2000);
  });
});
```

Could you please help me, why is it working with the normal button but not with submit.

Thank you very much.
hovrcraft.

Comment: The problem is because the `#power_off` button is of `type="submit"`, therefore the page will be unloaded as the form data is sent back to the server, hence no further JS logic will be executed. If you need this behaviour, don't use a submit button, or send an AJAX request instead of a form submission

Answer (score 1):

A submit button will **submit the form**.

So in the two seconds that `setTimeout` is waiting before evaluating your string, the browser has left the current page and loaded the new one (from the same URL, so it probably looks identical).

The timer isn't running in the new page, so it doesn't execute there.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you mate,
It was working like you said.
Now i have tried to copy your solution into my real case. Unfortunately it does not work now, as i need to send values to my webserver.

```
    $(document).ready(function(){ 

    $("#power_off").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault()
    $('#wert1').val('1');
    setTimeout(function(){
    $('#wert1').val('0');},1000);
    });
```

});

```
    <form method="post" action="" id="form">
            <input type="image" src="" value="" id="power_off" title="Anlage Ein">
            <input type="hidden" name='"DBEHmi".AnlageEin' value="" id="wert1" >
    </form>
```

As you can see i would like send a value of 1 after i clicked the image. After a time of 1000ms i want that the value is changing back to 0.

I have inserted the preventDefault function into my code, but now it seems like the page doesn't refresh anymore and doesn't send the value of 1.

Looking forward to your reply.

BR,
hovercraft

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){ 

    $("#power_off").click(function(e){
      e.preventDefault()
      setTimeout("alert('Boom!');", 2000);
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="post" action="" id="form">
            <input type="submit" value="Anlage Ein" id="power_off" title="Anlage Ein">
    </form>
</body>
```